# Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getNativeRequest

Tags: nosuchmethoderror

Handler processing failed; nested exception is `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getNativeRequest(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;` I am getting this error after submitting form

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have class WebUtils from Spring 2.5.x branch (this method has been added in 3.x branch).

Please check your dependencies and search for mixing of libraries from 3.x and 2.5.x branch.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Herewith adding the stacktrace 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getNativeResponse(Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
 at org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.saveContext(HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.java:109)